# group_concat() in sqlite returning undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

the same query in sqlite manager returning result here is how i create DB in sqlite manager [image: database creation], database insertion in sqlite manager [image: insertion] and retrieving values in sqlite-manager [image: group_concat on status col]while in phonegap-android its returning me undefined.i need result like the 3rd snapshot. i m inserting record using loop in phonegap-android.
here is the code of insertion:

```
function insertInUserPrayerTable() {


                        db.transaction(function(tx)
                         {for(var i = 0;i<checkedValueofCheckbox.length;i++)
                        {checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray.push('INSERT INTO user_prayers'

                             + '(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)'
                                + ' VALUES("'
                                + checkedValueofCheckbox[i]
                                + '",'
                                + window.localStorage
                                        .getItem("userid") + ',"'
                                + $('#datepicker').val() + '",'
                                + statusofNamaz[i] +');');

                console.log("array values:"+checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray);
                        }
                         },errorCB,runInsertQuery());

                         }
function runInsertQuery() {
                        db
                                .transaction(
                                        function(tx) {
                                            for (var i = 0; i < checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray.length; i++) {
                                                tx
                                                        .executeSql(
                                                                checkedValueofCheckboxInsertArray[i],
                                                                [],
                                                                successCBrunInsertQuery,
                                                                errorCBrunInsertQuery);
                                            }
                                        },errorCB,successCB);

                    }
```

i dnt know what m i doing wrong?

```
$('#showbtn')
.off('click')
.on('click', function() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT date,group_concat(status)"
            + " FROM user_prayers WHERE user_id ='"+window.localStorage.getItem("userid")+"'"
            + " GROUP BY date",
            [], successCBofselect, errorCBofselect);
    }, errorCB, successCB);
});

function successCBofselect(tx,results) {
    var htmlstring = "";
    if (results != null && results.rows != null && results.rows.length > 0) {
        console.log(results);<!-- [object SQLResultSet] -->
        console.log(results.rows);<!-- [object SQLResultSetRowList] -->
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            alert(""+results.rows.length);<!-- 8-->
            alert(""+results.rows.item(i)); <!-- [object object]-->
            deleteDataTemp[i] = results.rows.item(i).status;
            alert(""+deleteDataTemp[i]);<!-- undefined-->
            htmlstring += '</div>';
        }
        $("#data").empty().append(htmlstring).trigger('create');
    }
});
```

where "checkedValueofCheckbox[i]" is an array containing value sof all checked and unchecked checkboxes and "statusofNamaz[i]" containig an array of status either "1" or "0"
insertion console.log
05-14 16:21:16.335: I/Web Console(8505): array values:
INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("FAJR",1,"2013-05-15",1);,
INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("ZOHAR",1,"2013-05-15",1);,
INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("ASR",1,"2013-05-15",0);,
INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("MAGHRIB",1,"2013-05-15",0);,
INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ISHA",1,"2013-05-15",0); at file:///android_asset/www/js/PrayersManagerjs/namaz.js:144

need result 1,1,0,0,0 only status with group by date

Answer (score 1):

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT date,group_concat(status) FROM user_prayers  WHERE user_id ='"+ 
    window.localStorage.getItem("userid")+"' GROUP BY date" ...
```

The group_concat(status) will return null if there is no row which matches your WHERE clause. I guess that your table contains no row matching the user ID. Did you mean `window.localStorage.getItem("user_id")`? If you output that value to the console, is it what you expect?

Also, in general don't use string concatenation for building SQL statements. Use parameter binding instead, eg:

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT date,group_concat(status) FROM user_prayers WHERE user_id ='?' GROUP BY date",
    [window.localStorage.getItem("userid")] ...
```

It's more secure and in my opinion more readable too.

Comment: my WHERE condition is "true" and giving me user id i.e '1'

Comment: and also returning me "date" with group by clause applied on but only problem is it's not returning me the status value while same query is working fine in "sqlite manager"

Comment: Could you post the complete query you ran in SQLite Manager?

Comment: Also your CREATE TABLE statement and the results of the following query please: `SELECT * FROM user_prayers LIMIT 10;`

Comment: CREATE TABLE user_prayers ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,'user_id' INTEGER,'date' DATETIME,'status' INTEGER, "", "namazname" TEXT)                                                                    INSERT INTO user_prayers ('user_id','date','status') VALUES('1','2013-01-02','1'),('1','2013-01-02','0');                                                    SELECT date,group_concat(status)  FROM user_prayers WHERE user_id ='1' GROUP BY date

Comment: OK, your user_id column is an INTEGER column. Are you sure you didn't mean: `... FROM user_prayers WHERE user_id = " +window.localStorage.getItem("userid")+ " GROUP BY date ...`
in other words, get rid of the single-quotes for all the integer values..

Comment: yes user_id = 1 just forget about +window.localStorage.getItem("userid")+  line

Comment: You say the result is 'undefined'. Do you get an error somewhere? Which line of code? Throw in some console.log()s

    `if (results != null && results.rows != null && results.rows.length > 0) {
        console.log(results);
        console.log(results.rows);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(results.rows.item(i));
            deleteDataTemp[i] = results.rows.item(i).status;
            alert(""+deleteDataTemp[i]);
            htmlstring += '</div>';
        }
        $("#data").empty().append(htmlstring).trigger('create');
    }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29857/discussion-between-user1668447-and-bsa)

Comment: results.rows.item(i).status return "undefined" while results.rows.item(i) returns [object object]

Comment: Did you solve it? Please try:
  JSON.stringify(results.rows.item(i));
Also, where have you declared and initialized your deleteDataTemp variable?

Comment: JSON.stringify resolves some problems its giving me output but the whole output how can i print this result inisde of div like date in one column and 5 statuses in 5 different columns

Comment: console.log results after Applying JSON.stringify: JSON results:{"date":"2013-05-01","GROUP_CONCAT(prayer_id,status)":"11ZOHAR1ISHA0FAJR0ASR0MAGHRIB1FAJR1ZOHAR0ASR0MAGHRIB0ISHA"} at file:///android_asset/www/js/PrayersManagerjs/namaz.js:240
how can i separate values like FAJR and its status ,same for Zohar and its status

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Your result output shows GROUP_CONCAT(prayer_id,status) is being selected. That doesn't match the query in the code you posted. I have no idea where this is coming from.

Anyway, I've realised one problem. Use AS in your query for the group_concat, ie: "SELECT date,group_concat(status) AS status"

Comment: one more thing i m inserting values in this order:INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("FAJR",1,"2013-05-13",1);,INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ASR",1,"2013-05-13",1);,INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ZOHAR",1,"2013-05-13",0);,INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("MAGHRIB",1,"2013-05-13",0);,INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ISHA",1,"2013-05-13",0); at file:///android_asset/www/js/PrayersManagerjs/namaz.js:221

Comment: JSON results of my query which is not accurate:"date":"2013-05-13","PRAYERNAME":"1ASR1ZOHAR0MAGHRIB0ISHA0"}   which is the result of that query:   tx
         .executeSql("SELECT date,GROUP_CONCAT(status,prayer_id) AS 'PRAYER NAME' FROM  user_prayers WHERE user_id=1 GROUP BY date",[],successCBofselect,errorCBofselect);                                                                                                    but JSON result should be like this:JSON results:{"date":"2013-05-13","PRAYER NAME":"1FAJR1ASR0ZOHAR0MAGHRIB0ISHA" } what's the reason why its not displaying me accurate result

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think it's important for what you want. The important thing is, can you get the value you want now? Use an alias without a space (eg prayer_name). Then, what does results.rows.item(i).prayer_name evaluate to?

Comment: insert in this order:INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("ASR",1,"2013-05-12",1);                                                           INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status)VALUES("FAJR",1,"2013-05-12",0);  INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ZOHAR",1,"2013-05-12",0);                                   INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("MAGHRIB",1,"2013-05-12",0);                                  INSERT INTO user_prayers(prayer_id,user_id,date,status) VALUES("ISHA",1,"2013-05-12",0);

Comment: while i m getting value like this here is the console:            JSON results:{"date":"2013-05-12","PRAYER NAME":"1FAJR0ZOHAR0MAGHRIB0ISHA0"} WRONG VALUE while CORRECT VALUE SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:                                              JSON results:{"date":"2013-05-12","PRAYER NAME":"1ASR   0fajr   0ZOHAR  0MAGHRIB   0ISHA"}   OK HAVE GIVEN SPACES FOR READABILITY

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Just posting your output without any context (eg your code changes) is meaningless.

Don't take this the wrong way, but I think you should step back and think about / debug this for yourself. Make sure you understand every line of your code. Add your own debug output and make sure your values make sense. Do some reading if you don't. We can keep going back and forth 'debugging' like this, and we might eventually get to the result you want, but it's going to be frustrating for both of us and you're not going to learn anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30016/discussion-between-user1668447-and-bsa)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572030/group-concat-in-sqlite-returning-not-the-actual-data-as-it-is-inserted