# group_concat() in sqlite returning not the actual data as it is inserted

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

the query in sqlite manager returning not the axact data:here is my CREATE table statement:
[image: sqlite manager TABLE creation]
here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE user_prayers ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,'user_id' INTEGER,'date' DATETIME,'status' INTEGER, "", "namazname" TEXT)
```

insertion in DB:

```
INSERT INTO user_prayers (user_id,date,status,namazname) VALUES(1,'2013-01-05',1,"FAJR"),('1','2013-01-05',0,"ZOHAR"),('1','2013-01-05',1,"ASR"),('1','2013-01-05',0,"maghrib"),('1','2013-01-05',1,"ISHA");
```

which is successfully inserted here is the snapshot:pls forget about empty column
[image: insertion in DB]
now i need values of "STATUS" WITH its "NAMAZNAME" in the same order of insertion.for this reason using this query but failed to get result:

```
SELECT date,group_concat(status,namazname)  FROM user_prayers WHERE user_id ='1' GROUP BY date
```

and here is the snapshot of result:
 [image: select query result]
which is not accurate but i want result like  this "status" and its "namazname"
 **1  FAJR 0 ZOHAR 1 ASR 0 MAGHRIB 1 ISHA**
overhere in my query only 4 namazname are selected while the status are selected in the same order of insertion pls let me know what m i doing wrong to get "namazname" help me pls

Answer (score 1):

To get both the `status` and `namazname` values, you have to concatenate these strings (a second parameter of `group_concat` is the separator):

```
SELECT date, group_concat(status || ' ' || namazname, ' ')
FROM user_prayers
WHERE user_id = '1'
GROUP BY date
```

However, SQLite's `group_concat` function does not allow to specify an order; it always returns the values in an undefined order.